# how to draw gradient cover on a UIView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, core-animation

I really like this effect. I don't know how to draw a gradient shape like that. Please see the snapshot. I'm wondering how to make the gradient cover on the selected columns and rows in the picture.

http://maniacdev.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/TSTableView_Screenshot4.png

Answer (score 0):

You have to subclass UIView and override the DrawRect method. There you can draw whatever you want using CoreGraphics.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to draw a gradient with CAGraphicaLayer. But I didn't figure out how to draw a gradient for all the edges. Please see the picture, it has a four edges gradient.